# How to Layout responsive for All devices in Both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have to set my layout responsive for all devices because I am working on xamarin forms,
Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

I have tried the following code but font size differs as device differs.

```
    <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="45" Phone="20"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Named font sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#named-font-sizes) instead of specific value , the size values are measured in device-independent units.

The following table shows the NamedSize members, and their default sizes on iOS, Android, and the Universal Windows Platform (UWP):

[image]